# React, Node.js, Express.js: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for Recaptcha V2 contact form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, recaptcha

This is an issue that occurs during post production for my React app. The server and client sides of the project are in separate directories/folders. The server is built to verify the token for the recaptcha v2 and send the form on the contact page to the owner via Nodemailer. During development, whilst the server is running, there are no problems. However, this error is present during post production:

`POST http://localhost:8080/contact net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I have tried to use pm2 to keep the server running but this was unsuccessful.

**Contact.tsx**:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import axios from 'axios';

const Contact = () => {
  
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("SEND");
  const form = useRef();
  const firstnameRef = useRef();
  const lastnameRef = useRef();
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const messageRef = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(form.current);
    let details = {
      firstname: formData.get('firstname'),
      lastname: formData.get('lastname'),
      email: formData.get('email'),
      message: formData.get('message'),
    };
    const formValid = form.current.checkValidity();

    if (valid && formValid) {
    setStatus("SENDING...");
    try {
        let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/status", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(details),
        });
        let result = await response.json();
        alert(result.status);
        setStatus("SENT");
        form.current.reset();
        return;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        setStatus("FAILED");
      }
    } 
    else {
      alert("Please Verify You Are Not A Robot")
    }
  };

const captchaRef = useRef(null);

const reCaptchaValue = async () => {
  const token = captchaRef.current.getValue();
  await axios
    .post("http://localhost:8080/contact", {
      token: token,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      setValid(res.data.success);
      if (res.data.success === true) {
        setValid(true)
        alert('Verification Successful!');
      } else {
        setValid(false)
        alert("Please Verify You Are Not A Robot");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

  return (
        <div className='py-5 mobile:py-5 flex flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-5'>
            <form ref={form} onSubmit={handleSubmit} className=''>
              <input ref={firstnameRef} className='contact-input' type='text' name='firstname' placeholder='First Name' required />
              <input ref={lastnameRef} className='contact-input' type='text' name='lastname' placeholder='Surname' required />
              <input ref={emailRef} className='contact-input' type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email Address' required />
              <textarea ref={messageRef} required htmlFor="message"></textarea>
              <ReCAPTCHA 
              sitekey={process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_KEY}
              ref={captchaRef}
              onChange={() =>
              reCaptchaValue()}
              className='flex justify-center scale-75 tablet:scale-100'
              />
              <button type="submit" href="#_" disabled={!valid || status === "SENDING..."} className="relative inline-block text-lg group">
                  <span className="relative">{status}</span>
              </button>
          </form>
        </div>
    }
    </>
  )}

  export default Contact
```

**Server.js**:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const path = require('path');
const port =  8080;

require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env)

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cors());
app.use("/", router);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Server is running");
});

// Form Enquiry Nodemailer

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: "",
    pass: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_PASS}`,
  },
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Ready to Send");
  }
});

router.post("/status", async (req, res) => {

  const firstname = req.body.firstname;
  const lastname = req.body.lastname;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const message = req.body.message; 

  const mail = {
    from: "",
    to: "",
    subject: "",
    html: `<p>Enquiry From:<p>
           <p>Name: ${firstname} ${lastname}</p>
           <p>Email: ${email}</p>
           <br/>
           <p>Message: ${message}</p>`,
  };
  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ status: "ERROR" });
    } else {
      res.json({ status: "Message Sent" });
    }
  });
})

// ReCaptcha Verification

router.post("/contact", async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.body;
  const secret = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY}`;
  const captchaResponse = await axios.post(
    `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`,
    {
      secret: secret,
      response: token,
    }
  );
  if (captchaResponse.status === 200) {
    res.status(200).send({ success: true });
  } else {
    res.status(403).send({ success: false });
  }
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'..', 'client', 'build')));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('listening on port ', server.address().port);
});
```